# Discord.JS get member from user ID

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm pretty new to Discord.js and Stackoverflow. So I don't know exactly how to do this.

I do know that this question has been asked many times, sadly any I've found haven't worked.

I'm trying to assign roles to members on their birthday. I want to do this with a crontab.
Now I have their user ID's but sadly when I request the member with this code.

```
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID');
let member = guild.members.cache.get('User ID');
console.log(member);
```

I just get an `undefined` message. Now I know that the user ID is correct. I just don't know why I get the `undefined` message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID');
let member = guild.members.cache.get('User ID');
```

I prefer to use something like:

```js
let person = client.members.cache.get('User ID');
console.log(person);
```

If you still have problems, you will have to enable the **Intents** on the Discord Developers Portal

Image:

[image]

Comment: It turned out that indeed the intent needed to be turned on. Thank you for taking the time I'm getting the correct user now!

Answer (score 2):

The cache probably doesn't have the user so you should try this method instead: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch.